# Obtendo objetos com JQuery e enviando via Ajax para MVC C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando entender como receber objetos do HTML para um controller MVC C#.
Sei que o código abaixo, funciona se no controller tiver `string[]  teste`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="teste">
<input type="hidden" name="teste" value="testes">
<input type="hidden" name="teste" value="testes1">
```

Mas vi alguns códigos, principalmente para data grids, que cria filtro genérico, aonde os valores de campo, tipo de filtro e valor, as propriedades recebem `nomePropriedade_1`.

Como faço para tratar isto no JQuery, e como devo tratar isto no controller do MVC C#?

Exemplos:

http://www.pontikis.net/labs/bs_grid/demo/

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-new-field-on-focus-or-change

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multiple-fields-contact-form

Comment: Você irá usar listas de variáveis primitivas ou objetos complexos?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez na verdade queria aprender com ambos..O que vier de ajuda, está de bom tamanho.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Entendendo o `ModelBinder` do ASP.NET MVC

Basicamente o que o `ModelBinder` faz é tentar conciliar os nomes e valores dos campos de um formulário (no caso de POST) ou de uma requisição (no caso de GET). Considere primeiro seu exemplo:

```
<input type="hidden" name="teste">
<input type="hidden" name="teste" value="testes">
<input type="hidden" name="teste" value="testes1">
```

Neste caso, se o formulário fosse enviado a um método do `Controller` assinado da seguinte forma:

```
public ActionResult MinhaAction(string[] teste) { ... }
```

O `ModelBinder` identificaria uma variável de nome `teste` com 3 valores: vazio, `"testes"` e `testes1`, e corretamente criaria uma lista para eles, como mencionado na pergunta.

A lógica se estende para toda e qualquer lista, com a diferença que no formulário estejam expressas informações suficientes para que o `ModelBinder` possa fazer a correspondência.

Suponha agora que eu queira que meu método receba agora um objeto complexo. Suponha o seguinte `ViewModel`:

```
public class MeuViewModel {
    public String NomeProduto { get; set; }
    public String NomeComprador { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
}
```

Posso ter um formulário assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel.NomeProduto" value="Coca Cola">
<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel.NomeComprador" value="Cigano">
<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel.Quantidade" value="1">
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
<input type="hidden" name="NomeProduto" value="Coca Cola">
<input type="hidden" name="NomeComprador" value="Cigano">
<input type="hidden" name="Quantidade" value="1">
```

E uma `Action` assinada com o seguinte argumento:

```
public ActionResult MinhaSegundaAction(MeuViewModel meuViewModel) { ... }
```

O `ModelBinder` irá preencher as informações corretamente.

Agora, para o caso de listas de objetos complexos, é preciso indexar. Isso pode ser feito de duas maneiras:

- Por índices numéricos;
- Por `Guid`s, feito, por exemplo, por pacotes NuGet como o [MvcBeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/)

Basicamente, posso fazer o seguinte:

```
<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel[0].NomeProduto" value="Coca Cola">
<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel[0].NomeComprador" value="Cigano">
<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel[0].Quantidade" value="1">

<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel[1].NomeProduto" value="Guaraná">
<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel[1].NomeComprador" value="Marlon">
<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel[1].Quantidade" value="2">

<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel[2].NomeProduto" value="Água Tônica">
<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel[2].NomeComprador" value="Fulano">
<input type="hidden" name="meuViewModel[2].Quantidade" value="3">
```

O `ModelBinder` é capaz de entender que isso deve virar uma lista se o método assim estiver assinado:

```
public ActionResult MaisUmaAction(List<MeuViewModel> meuViewModel) { ... }
```

Mas, e no caso do JSON?

Bom, a partir do MVC3, uma `Action` já consegue receber JSON porque a classe `JsonValueProviderFactory`, que alimenta o `ModelBinder`, já vem registrada por padrão. Ou seja, posso mandar o mesmo formulário por Ajax da seguinte forma:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/MeuController/MaisUmaAction',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: [
        {
            "NomeProduto": "Coca Cola",
            "NomeComprador": "Cigano",
            "Quantidade": 1
        },
        {
            "NomeProduto": "Coca Cola",
            "Nome": "Marlon",
            "Quantidade": 2
        },
        {
            "NomeProduto": "Água Mineral",
            "Nome": "Fulano",
            "Quantidade": 3
        }
        ],
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) {
            var message = data.Message;
            $("#flash").html("Sucesso! " + message);
        }
});
```